# Print entire mysql table with php

Tags: php, mysql

I know the basics of HTML, and nothing about PHP. I've found a ton of tutorials, but I couldn't get a single one to work. I have a mySQL database working and apache running. How can I display an entire table on my page? I do not know the column names ahead of time.

Edit: Added and adjusted the code. My index page shows this: `connect_errno) { echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error; } //$sql = "SHOW TABLES"; $sql = "select * from cpu"; //edit your table name here $res = $mysqli->query($sql); while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) { print_r($row); } ?>`

This is my entire index.html source:

```
<?php

    $mysqli = new mysqli("192.168.1.2", "webuser", "*****", "OCN");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    //$sql = "SHOW TABLES"; 
    $sql = "select * from cpu";  //edit your table name here
    $res = $mysqli->query($sql);

    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        print_r($row);
    }
?>
```

Once I changed my file to .php, the error message was more clear. It reminded me that I didn't have webuser at 192.168.1.2. I created the user again and gave the correct permissions. The function appears to work, but I'll have more time in a few hours to look at it.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp read this it's just need letle adjustment to makebit work for you

Comment: I've come across this page before. What is the adjustment? Again, I know next to nothing about PHP.

Comment: Just a quick notice, if your file is really called `index.html` then you should rename it to `index.php` since it contains php code.

Comment: After changing that, it made the error message clear. I was able to figure out it was denying me access, not that it was unable to find the server.

Comment: You have a mysql server running on a different machine on your lan? If Apache and MySQL are on the same machine change ip to localhost or 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem here is that you see `connect_errno) { echo "Failed to...` on your page, instead of a line beginning with `Failed to...` only.

Because your browser thinks that the code from `<?php` to `$mysqli->` is an HTML tag (because of the opening and closing `<>`, I think your file is a .htm(l) file rather than a .php file.

Just change the file extension and if PHP is installed correctly it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "database");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    //$sql = "SHOW TABLES"; 
    $sql = "select * from tbl_comment";  //edit your table name here
    $res = $mysqli->query($sql);

    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        print_r($row);
    }
?>
```

Comment: @TylerMontney looks your code unable to connect with 192.168.1.2 try localhost if you are working with XAMPP or WAMP

Comment: Hmm, that shouldn't be. My VB app has no issue connecting. My database is not running on the same PC.

Comment: according to error you are getting  only means  "Failed to connect to MySQL:" you are unable to connect with database. please double check mysql connection.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood. You want to display values but you don't know column names.
If that's so, try this.

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli("192.168.1.2", "webuser", "*****", "OCN");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    //$sql = "SHOW TABLES"; 
    $sql = "select * from cpu";  //edit your table name here
    $res = $mysqli->query($sql);

    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        foreach($row as $ind => $val)
        {
            echo "Column name: $ind, Column Value: $val<br />";
        }
        echo "<hr />";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Issue I'm having at the moment is I can't connect. I don't know why because I'm not having trouble connecting in other ways. Once I can fix that, I'll try this.